# Docker - port 443: No route to host

Tags: docker

I'm trying to reach a company internal registry. I have bashed into the container and when I curl the URL I get:

```
port 443: No route to host
```

I can reach the registry from outside of the container. I have tried to use `--network host` when running the container but it doesn't help. What can be wrong?

---

Found the issue and it's super weird.

I had to deactivate Kubernetes in Docker Desktop, quit Docker Desktop and start it again.

Basically I found a strange `cni0` when I did `ifconfig` and I traced it to Kubernetes by googling. Then I just guessed that it had to do with Docker Desktop as I had Kubernetes enabled there. It didn't work to press the "Apply & Restart" button though in the Docker Desktop app. I had to quit the app and start it again.

With Kubernetes disabled the `cni0` disappeared and I could access the internal registry.

Comment: Is this a local container? Can you reach the URL from the host?

Comment: Yes it's a local container and yes it can be reached from host.
Edit: Thanks for clearing it out.

Comment: Can you show us the exact curl command you run? (You can change the domain to a placeholder btw)

Comment: `curl -I {URL}`

Comment: What dist/version are you using? Is there a firewall running?

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems that on some RHEL/CentOs distributions it can be a firewall issue. Take a look at [this docker discussion](https://forums.docker.com/t/no-route-to-host-network-request-from-container-to-host-ip-port-published-from-other-container/39063/12). I think you have probably encountered the same problem